# Integrating the PDF of a t-distribution in R via integrate()

Tags: r, integration, t-test

I am trying to replicate the t-test with mathematical formulas and it somehow wont work with may current attempt below:

```
# PDF t-distribution:
t_distr = function(x,df){
  t_1 = gamma((df+1)/2)/(sqrt(df*pi)*gamma(df/2))
  t_2 = (1 + (seq^2/df))^(-(df+1)/2)
  t_distr = t_1*t_2
  return(t_distr)
} # End of function

# Initialize Sequence: 
seq = seq(-4,4,by = .1)

# Integrating up to t-value of 1 (lower tail t-test):
integrate(t_distr, df = length(seq)-1, lower = -Inf, upper = 1 )

# For df = length(seq)-2 (e.g. for a lin. reg):
integrate(t_distr, df = length(seq)-2, lower = -Inf, upper = 1 )
```

The above code will result in the following error message:

```
Error in integrate(t_distr, df = length(seq) - 1, lower = -Inf, upper = 1) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

Any suggestions how to make it possible to integrate the pdf of a t-distribution using the integrate function? It also does not work with a "df" of just n...

Comment: In your t function, what is `seq`?

Comment: Use t.test function. This has nothing to do with the t distribution unless you want the pvalue

Comment: You have `dt` for density,  `pt` for probability  and `qt` for quantile. You could easily use hose. Or do you want to implement your own?

Comment: I know that these functions exist, but I want to recreate it via using the actual formulas. And what I want is the p-value that is why I am trying to integrate.... I did the same already for the z-test.... Now I want to do it via the PDF of a t-distribution as well. Apart from that: a t-test does not result in a t-distribution but a t-value on a PDF of a t-distribution. However, thanks anyway....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. Your `t_distr` function uses `seq` which is not defined (actually it is defined to be function, later you overwrite it with a vector, avoid that). You want your `t_distr` (the density of the `t` distribution) to take one argument `x`:

   ```r
   t_distr <- function(x, df){
     t_1 <- gamma((df + 1) / 2) / (sqrt(df * pi) * gamma(df / 2))
     t_2 <- (1 + (x ^ 2 / df)) ^ (-(df + 1) / 2)
     t_1 * t_2
   }
   ```

   (you can check that your `t` density is correctly defined by `all.equal(t_distr(2.123, 12), dt(2.123, 12))`.
2. For `integrate` (to move from the desnity to the cdf) you need to provide your function and limits. The function will then be integrated in its first argument:

   ```r
   integrate(t_distr, df = 12, lower = -Inf, upper = 1)
   ```

   this will integrate your density from `-Inf` to `1` with `12` degrees of freedom. Again we can check whether we got the correct results by comparing that to the built-in cdf of the `t`-distribution:

   ```r
   all.equal(integrate(t_distr, df = 12, lower = -Inf, upper = 1)$value, pt(1, 12))
   ```
3. The degrees of freedom have actually nothing to do with the integration itself and should be seen as an additional parameter. Maybe that's were the confusion came from.

Comment: Thanks so much! "seq" within the function was the problem indeed!! In a former version I used seq instead of x.

Comment: `R` lexical scoping is a bless and a curse. As `seq`  is not defined in the body of `t_distr` it will be looked up in the global environment and all the way up  to the base namespace (where the function is defined). However, as you overwrote `seq` by a vector this error is even more difficult to spot, because now we use at least some numerics instead of a function. Bototm line: avoid at all costs to re-use pre-defined names (`c`, `data` are classics).